# Smoke Domain renders black

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

so very odd things, I have seen this in other places, but nothing has fixed it as of yet.
In any mode that isn't Rendered, it works 100% fine:

[image]

However, it does seem to be completely blacked out in Rendered view and when I render it:

[image]

I have tried a lot of different solutions, but to no real avail. Thank you for reading

Comment: So you have lights etc? We need to know what, not if you tried.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Please add images that show how you set up your domain and textures.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18599/smoke-domain-object-is-black and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/quick-smoke-domain-is-solid-black and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50241/blender-2-77-renders-smoke-fire-domain-solid-black-on-gpu-cycles

Comment: I have tried lights, Im in cycles, I've checked and un-checked adaptive domain and I've tried pretty much every setting in User Preferances. Here's the URL for the .blend https://files.fm/u/

Comment: https://files.fm/u/7k9b8sbb Sorry, it got cut off